# Data storage interrupt when shorting the CAN bus

Tags: microcontroller, interrupts, can

In the [MPC5674](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/power-architecture-processors/mpc5xxx-55xx-32-bit-mcus/ultra-reliable-mpc56xx-32-bit-automotive-and-industrial-microcontrollers-mcus/ultra-reliable-mpc5674f-mcu-for-automotive-industrial-engine-management:MPC5674F) microcontroller, when creating a short circuit in the CAN bus, the controller is getting restarted repeatedly.

The root cause of this reset has been found to be due to a 'data storage interrupt'.

What is the data storage interrupt? And why is it caused when creating a short circuit in a CAN channel?

Comment: You may answer your own question. This will be helpful for others as you have solution.

Comment: The comment which i have given is the actual solution

Comment: I am suggesting to post your comment as answer and then accept it. It will remove this question from "Unanswered".

Comment: yeah, i would accept this. These many days i didnt aware about this would be listed in "Unanswered question"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the Root Cause : In c code there is common interrupt handling functionality for both CAN (Two can buses available) buses.

CAN1 having 64 Message objects. And CAN2 having 32 message objects, whenever creating short its trying to clear the 64 Interrupt flags but whereas only 32 interrupt flags allocated for CAN2